# 500 error after updating htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication, httpd.conf

I've been working through "PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, & CSS" by Robin Nixon, and have hit a brick wall with the Basic Authentication in PHP section: the login pop-up won't accept a correct username and password and instead loops.  So I tried editing the server's config settings.  I'm **using the Apache2 server**, and have (I think) set up authentication and authorization through configuring `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`, but I am now getting a `500 internal server error`. I'm new to php so it's perhaps likely that i have missed a step or misunderstood a step, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
In `httpd.conf` i have added the following:

```
<Directory "...\Apache2/htdocs">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentication Required"
    AuthUserFile "...Apache2\passwd"
    Require valid-user
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is this where i am going wrong?

Comment: 500 internal server error is most likely a PHP issue. Can you provide a little code? Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to keep your code in code tags in the future so that it's easier to read. I've edited your post for you but please feel free to edit it yourself if you have any additional info!

Comment: What's the `.htaccess` look like? Loops in `.htaccess` can also cause 500 errors.